# How do I make the DataGridView show the selected row(Winforms)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Hi I m working on windows application.How do i make selected row in the datagridview when i changed select any row in daragridview ?

Please help me.

Comment: You do what when what? Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: You should make your question clearer... do you want to select the whole row when the user clicks in one cell?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it will make your datagridview select all row whenever the user clicks in one cell

```
YourDataGridView.SelectionMode=DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Comment: which event i used in this line to write.?

Comment: you can add this in the `form_load` event

Comment: I select one row then click on edit button at that time selected row it should be selected..but in above case after click on edit button bydefault first row to be select.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go ... Auto updated DataGridView row 
Added at the top all the time every time.

```
 DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
 int rowID = 0;

 dgvLocation.Rows.Insert(rowID, row);

 dgvLocation.Rows[rowID].Cells[0].Value = Number.ToString();
 dgvLocation.Rows[rowID].Cells[1].Value = Time.ToString();
 dgvLocation.Rows[rowID].Cells[2].Value = History1.ToString();
 dgvLocation.Rows[rowID].Cells[3].Value = History2.ToString();

 dgvLocation.Rows[rowID].Selected = true;
 dgvLocation.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int currRow = 0;
currRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
dataGridView1.Rows[currRow].Selected = true;
```

Comment: I select one row then click on edit button at that time selected row it should be selected..but in above case after click on edit button bydefault first row to be select.

Comment: What you are asking is not clear can you elobrate more or post some images as per your requirement